# document.getElementByID() in Node.js using express

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know if it's possible to get an Element by ID using express.

If it's not possible, I'm using express to transmit data from my website to my node.js server. Is it possbile to get a text input from the user, and then apply that in a node.js variable?

If that's not possible, I'll commit to websockets :(

Comment: Well, no. First, there's no global `document` variable on backend side (it can be serving countless documents and doing several other things beside that), and second, the backend doesn't have realtime access to the client machine's state. Which is a good thing. You must implement _some_ kind of API (doesn't have to be sockets).

Comment: Thank you! I will use WebSockets, as I have experience with them. Thank you!

Comment: When you load an HTML *document* in a browser you create an environment you can run JS in centred about the document. when you load JS in Node.js there is no HTML document, so what `document` would you get the ID from? There are ways to create a document object in Node.js, but would they be useful to you? It sounds like you need want to deal with the way a user interacts with a document in a browser. Is that the case? You should provide more details about what you are trying to achieve as this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

USER CLICKS BUTTON => NODE.JS SERVER DOES SOMETHING;
USER WRITES STUFF => NODE.JS SERVER GETS THE INPUT, AND DOES SOMETHING

Comment: Well, send a request to your node http server when the user clicks the button and do the same once the user has written their stuff.

Comment: @Edvinas55 — That sounds like something most easily achieved with a regular `<form>` submission.

Comment: You don't think I tried the <form> submission?
Bot GET and POST for submissions DO NOT WORK.
So, unless theres a node.js function, go on!

Comment: "You don't think I tried the `<form>` submission?" — There's no evidence of you trying that in your question.

Comment: "Bot GET and POST for submissions DO NOT WORK." — That's not enough information for anyone to help you debug it.

Comment: "So, unless theres a node.js function, go on!" — You said you were using Express: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms

Comment: THANK YOU, QUENTIN! YOU ANSWERED IT!
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want real-time update, then websocket is your only option (instead of sending HTTP request each time user inputs, which will flood your server).

However, if you don't really need real-time interaction, you can use old-way form POST (or any) method and send HTTP request to your express backend at the end with the data from the form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Because the backend does not have real-time access to the client's machine state, the only way to use `getElementByID()`, is to `npm install an API`.

For my website, I will be using web sockets.
This can also be a good thing as if the website gets DDOS, then it will not affect my node.js server.

Thank you, @mbojko for providing me with this answer!